# Shopify API: How to get id where is greater than

Tags: rest, shopify, shopify-api

How can I get orders thru Shopify API where the id is greater than xxxxx?

Something like:

```
admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?id>=1900000000
```

or

```
admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?min_id=1900000000
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation you see that orders have a created_at_min and created_at_max. Those values are what you use as your filter criteria for dates. If you need to work off of ID then you can try the since_id filter. In other words, give me all order since 123456. You get what I mean?